# Pop-up box asking user multiple questions

Tags: google-sheets

I have the below so far, which I've found from this site.

This creates a rather large box which unfortunately only asks (and returns) one value - the name.

Is there a way for me to add multiple questions (such as age, date of birth) and return the responses to the appropriate cells within the same pop up box?

In other words I want **one** box to pop up that the user can enter text in for each of the three questions, *then* press okay to submit their responses.

```
function getInputFromNameBox() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Create the user interface
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //Create one textboxs
  var tBox1 = app.createTextBox().setName('tBox1').setId('tBox1');
  //Create the OK button and a handler to respond to when OK is clicked.
  var okHandler = app.createServerHandler('respondToOK');
  var btnOK = app.createButton('OK', okHandler);
  //I find grids very handy for arranging labels and widgets like textboxes neatly
  var myGrid = app.createGrid(2, 2).setId('myGrid')
    .setText(0, 0, 'Your Name')
    .setWidget(0, 1, tBox1)
    .setWidget(1, 1, btnOK);
  /*The OK button's handler needs a callback element otherwise it can't read the user's input.
    You could add multiple callback elements to each of the textboxes but that's just extra code.
    As all the textboxes are added to myGrid then just one callback to that will work fine.
  */
  okHandler.addCallbackElement(myGrid);
  app.add(myGrid);
  ss.show(app);
}

function respondToOK(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var result = e.parameter.tBox1;
  //Enter the result in the cell C5
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellAddress = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("rangeUserName").setValue(result); //Change to cell you want populated (you can create copies of this row to have multiple submissions of the value.
  //Close the user interface
  return app.close();
}
```

Comment: UiApp has been deprecated since 2014, use this instead. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: Thank you but I'm a real novice at this.  I'm not sure how I'd incorporate that new function into the above text, or how I'd get it to ask two questions in the pop up box.